# Bash grep, awk o sed to reverse find

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I am creating a script to look for commonly used patterns in a password.Although I have security policies in the hosting panel, servers have been outdated due to incompatibilities.

Example, into the file words.txt, i put in there, the word `test`, when i execute `grep -c test123 words.txt`. When I look for that pattern I need it to find it but I think that with the command `grep` it won't work for me.

Script:

```
EMAILPASS=`/root/info.sh -c usera | grep @`

for PAR in ${EMAILPASS} ; do

EMAIL=$(echo "${PAR}" | grep @ | cut -f1 -d:)
PASS=$(echo "${PAR}" | cut -d: -f 2)
PASS="${PASS,,}"
FINDSTRING=$(grep -ic "${PASS}" /root/words.txt)

echo -e ""
echo -e "Validating password ${EMAIL}"
echo -e ""


if [ $FINDSTRING -ge 1 ] ; then
echo "Insecre"
else
echo "Secure"
fi
```

the current output of the command is as follows

```
# grep -c test123 /root/words.txt
0
```

I think grep is not good for what I need, maybe someone can help me.

I could also use awk or sed but I can't find an option to help me.

Regardsm

Answer (score 0):

Reverse your application.

```
echo test123 | grep -f words.txt
```

Each line of the text file will be used as a pattern to test against the input.

## edit

Apparently you actually do want to see if the whole password is an actual word, rather than just checking to see if it's based on a dictionary word. That's considerably less secure, but easy enough to do. The logic you have will not report `test123` as insecure unless the whole passwword is an exact match for a word in the dictionary.

You said you were putting `test` in the dictionary and using `test123` as the password, so I assumed you were looking for passwords *based* on dictionary words, which was the structure I suggested above. Will include as commented alternate lines below.

Also, since you're doing a case insensitive search, why bother to downcase the password?

```
declare -l pass                          # set as always lowecase
```

would do it, but there's no need.

Likewise, unless you are using it again later, it isn't necessary to put everything into a variable first, such as the `grep` results. Try to remove anything not needed -- less is more.

Finally, since we aren't catching the `grep` output in a variable and testing that, I threw it away with `-q`. All we need to see is whether it found anything, and the return code, checked by the `if`, tells us that.

```
/root/info.sh -c usera | grep @ |        # only lines with at signs
  while IFS="$IFS:" read email pass      # parse on read with IFS
  do printf "\n%s\n\n" "Validating password for '$email'"
     if grep -qi "$pass" /root/words.txt # exact search (-q = quiet)
    #if grep -qif /root/words.txt <<< "$pass" # 'based on' search
     then echo "Insecure"
     else echo "Secure"                  # well....
     fi
  done
```

I think a better paradigm might be to just report the problematic ones and be silent for those that seem ok, but that's up to you.

Questions?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that way the condition in the `if` doesn't work for me:  

`echo string123 | grep -cf /root/words.txt`

Is equal to 1.

`echo string345 | grep -cf /root/words.txt` equal to 1

I could also use awk or sed but I can't find an option to help me.